# Filter certain data on post object ACF

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

want to ask.

I have ACF field that use post object. I want to send the value from post object field using url. The result show it send all detail.

What I do is:

```
$field['choices'] = array();
$choices = get_field('t2_first_name',$post->ID);
$query = http_build_query(array('aParam' => $choices));

$cpage = home_url('/?datasend='.$query);

//button to send data in url
echo '<a class="cst-btn cst-btn-'.$color.'" href="'.$cpage.'" >Submit</a>';
```

Result show:

```
{"post_author":"3998","post_date":"2020-04-05 05:23:10","post_date_gmt":"2020-04-04 21:23:10","post_content":"","post_title":"183303P","post_excerpt":"","post_status":"publish","comment_status":"closed","ping_status":"closed","post_password":"","post_name":"183303p","to_ping":"","pinged":"","post_modified":"2020-04-05 05:23:10","post_modified_gmt":"2020-04-04 21:23:10","post_content_filtered":"","post_parent":"0","guid":"http:\/\/www.mekcas.a2hosted.com\/trainer\/183303p\/","menu_order":"0","post_type":"trainer","post_mime_type":"","comment_count":"0","filter":"raw"}
```

How can I filter only "post_title" send using url? Anyone can help?

Comment: How would you like the href in the button to look?

Comment: I want to look like this: [link](www.example.com/?datasend=183303P) @Tokant

Comment: So you want to capture the query variable 'datasend', when visitors click the submit link, and filter the result by 'post_title'?

Comment: yes. but the post_title is based on post object `$choices = get_field('t2_first_name',$post->ID);` this field is using post object ACF

Comment: I also try something like this:
`$posts = get_field('t2_first_name',$post->ID);

    if ($posts):
     foreach ($posts as $post):
      setup_postdata($post);
      $query = $post_title->ID;
     endforeach;
     wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;`
but it did not send any data

Comment: If all you want is to grab 'post_title' from $choices and add it to the datasend query var, simply get $choices['post_title'] and add it to the query. Like $query = http_build_query(array('aParam' => $choices['post_title']));

Comment: hmm..when i create as your suggest, my button not appear

Comment: What if you omit $query = http_build_query(array('aParam' => $choices));, and add the post_title to the $cpage variable? Like this $cpage = home_url('/?datasend='.$choices['post_title']);

Comment: @tokant I will try this and show the result

Comment: @Tokant this also make button not appear. maybe because an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
if( $post_object ):
    $name = get_the_title($post_object->ID);
wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```

this work for me. It filter only the title of post_object (based on selected ACF field)